# Multiple MDPI/HDPI drawables with different for same

Tags: android, image, resources, drawable

I am new to android and this concept of multiple resources is killing me and its Halloween =)

Ok so for Normal screen we have following HDPI per http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range

WVGA800 (480x800) 
WVGA854 (480x854) 
600x1024

so my image will go in drawable-hdpi. should image be 480x800, 480x854, 600x1024, or all 3 in the drawable-hdpi?

If all 3 are doing to be in drawable-hdpi, how I will name them? They can't have same names.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common drawable folders are drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-ldpi.

These folders are used to tell android which set of image to use on different situations. 
The different names that can be used are given [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

When a small ldpi phone is being used and it tries to refer an image named icon.png. It first refers the drawable-ldpi folder. If it doesn't find it there, it moves to the other folders till it finds the image. But if the phone was an hdpi device, android would first look into the drawable-hdpi folder. So if icon should be of different sizes, you put the different sized image in each folder with the same name. And android will decide which folder to access the image in run time.

This might be a bit confusing in the beginning but you will get used to it after a while.

Comment: understood. But Android site has 2 resolutions for Normal screen ldpi WQVGA400 (240x400) 
WQVGA432 (240x432)   Being said that should I create an image of 240x432 and put it in ldpi or both? 2 images with same name can't be in ldpi folder. I appreciate your time

Comment: To some extent our designs should be able to scale on different phones. Use 9 patch images as possible. I mainly create designs for 3 resolutions 240*320,320*480,480*800. Sometimes i tell my layouts to wrap to the images size and some to fill the remaining space. Its not always perfect but its how its done. But another way will be to programatically check the screen size and then tell which image to use. In that case you can use different names but its just too much work and all the images can make your build size go up.

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes sense now. Highly appreciate your time.